# Outofmemory error in java

Tags: java, out-of-memory

hi we are getting out of memory exception for one of our process which is running in unix environmnet . how to identify the bug (we observed that there is very little chance of memory leaks in our java process). so whatelse we need analyse to find the rootcauase

Comment: >>we observed that there is very little chance of memory leaks in our java process

What actually have you done to come to this conclusion? Did you use JMX and monitored the heap usage? What actually is the application trying to do?

Comment: @anil: if your Java code is as nicely written as both your question and your question title, I suggest double looking at the code to make sure it's not leaking ;)

Comment: Fortunately you're not the first who encountered this problem, so there are pretty much questions (and answers) regarding the subject :) http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=outofmemoryerror The standard answer is: "First profile (http://java-source.net/open-source/profilers) the application and depending on the outcome, either fix the memory leak or give it more memory". There is really no other way.

Comment: When you say: "there is very little chance of memory leaks in our java process" it sounds like you mean: "There is nothing wrong with my program, what else could cause the error?" Unless you have run a memory profiler as others have suggested, it is difficult for people to believe that there is nothing wrong with your program. Generally one can assume first that the problem is in their program, not in unix, or the JVM. That's not to say that those things don't have bugs, but rather the odds of having a bug in a program you wrote is much higher than finding a bug in unix or the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a profiler like **YourKit** ([homepage](http://www.yourkit.com/)) so that you can easily find what is allocating so much memory.

In any case you should check which settings are specified for your JVM to understand if you need more heap memory for your program. You can set it by specifying `-X` params:

```
java -Xmx2g -Xms512m
```

would start JVM with 2Gb of maximum heap and a starting size of 512Mb

Answer (score 0):

If there are no memory leaks then the application needs more memory. Are you getting out of heap memory, or perm memory or native memory? For heap memory and perm memory you can increase allocation using -Xmx.or -XX:PermSize arguments respectively.

But first try using a profiler to verify that your application is really not leaking any memory.